# how do I change the path used for rails assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do I change the path used for assets in production? I'm pushing the assets to a CDN, but rails keeps putting /assets/ in front of the file name but this isn't the path on the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

found it

config.assets.prefix

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets